# Segue to same view Controller loads before prepareforsegue is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

Hi guys i am a beginner on Obj c Programming, I have created a "self segue"(segue to same view controller) from a tableviewcell. Now my problem is, i am setting few parameters in the prepareForSegue method, but somehow the segue already happens before this method is called(i am not even calling "performSeguewithIdentifier"). I understand that this might be because the segue is associated with the cell. But i found no other way to create a "self-segue"

please help.Btw i am using xcode6..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
 _selctdObj =  [avObjArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 if([_selctdObj isContainer])
  {
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"isContainerSegue" sender:self];
  } 
 else
  {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"isItemSegue" sender:self];
  }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"isContainerSegue"]) {
    // Get destination view
    serverBrowseVC *sbvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    [sbvc setServerSelected:_serverSelected];
    [sbvc setBrowseObjID:_selctdObj];

 }
}
```

Now invariably "isContainerSegue" gets executed ,even is the object is not a container. i also tried commenting the

```
//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"isContainerSegue" sender:self];
```

But every time "isContainerSegue" gets executed..

Comment: What is the purpose of this self segue? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i am trying to browse a Upnp container(you can relate to browsing a folder). so i need to browse recursively until it reaches a playable item.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I can set parameters in prepareForSegue, and they work fine in the destination controller. You need to show what code you're putting in prepareForSegue, and how you're using those parameters in the destination view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you weren't calling performSegueWithIdentifier, but you are. You shouldn't be if you've connected the segue from the cell. You also shouldn't implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath at all, just prepareForSegue. You can get the indexPath from the sender argument (the sender will be the cell) of prepareForSegue:sender:. If you're having a problem with the "if [_selctdObj isContainer]" clause, you need to post what isContainer does.

Comment: thanks @rdelmar for replying. The problem is exactly that, i dont want the segue to be executed automatically unless i call "[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"isContainerSegue" sender:self]". But the only way i am able to crete a self segue in xcode 6 is by associating a segue with a cell.When i control drag from ViewController icon in storyboard to anywhere other than the cell i am not getting the "segue" option.

Comment: @AkshayVernekar, Then don't use a segue. Just instantiate a new instance of your controller, then push or present it. There's no particular reason you need to do this with a segue.

Comment: Thankyou @rdelmar .. i Guess thats the way to do it.